# Instancia DAL aparece como variable desconocida, Web2py

Tags: python, base-de-datos, model, web2py

Estoy comenzando a utilizar Web2py y estoy siguiendo el tutorial, pero me esta pasando un problema, aparentemente las instancias como DAL y Field funcionan pero me aparecen con error en el Visual Studio, como si no estuviera importando estos métodos(DAL,Field), en el tutorial no explican si hay que hacer algún import o algo.

Al parecer las instancias funcionan con la base a la que se conecta en el tutorial, pero he intentado conectarme a una MSSQl y no funciona, no se si es por los errores antes mencionados o pasa por otra cosa.

Les dejo una captura de como se ve el código.

[image: Las instancias aparecen en color amarillo como una advertencia de Variable Desconocida]

Si alguien mas a podido solucionar esto, se los agradeceria mucho.
De antemano gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El linter se queja y con mucha razón porque efectivamente no están definidos los nombres `DAL`, `Field` y `IS_NOT_EMPTY` en ese módulo.

Importa al inicio del módulo los tres nombres requeridos, en este caso:

```
from pydal import DAL, Field
from pydal.validators import IS_NOT_EMPTY
```

Comment: Lo estuve intentando hacer pero no funcionaba porque cuando abrí el folder de  mi proyecto con VSC , no estaba incluyendo las carpetas donde estaba la clase pydal, así que abrí todo el folder de Web2py e inclui las lineas que me dijiste y funciona perfecto, gracias!